# Cannot protect the color of my svg when using mouseover method

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I have some circles created in for loop and I want to change the color of these circles to red when mouse hovers over them. **But when mouse loses the focus on these circles, I want them to protect the color they had before mouse hovered over them.** But since the circles are created by for loop, I am not sure about how to do that.

The arrays are :

```
analyzedUnique = [34675791162, 10132910658, 10588895486, 10609894726, 14794759174, 1790587656, 18895624430, 3610288229, 4170058208, 5550074705, 7600064469]

[1790587656: "blue", 3610288229: "orange", 4170058208: "blue", 34675091162: "blue", 10132910658: "orange", 10588895486: "orange", 10609894726: "orange", 14794759174: "blue"…]
```

checkCustomer array is the numbers of people with a color assigned to them stating if the customer is an engineer.

```
for (i = 0; i < numberOfCirclesShown - 2 ; i++) { 

  var circle  = svg.append("circle")

  .attr("cx", circleR + r - r * cosDegrees(alpha * (i+1)))

  .attr("cy", firstCircleY - r * sinDegrees(alpha * (i+1)))

  .attr("r", circleR)

  .style("fill", checkCustomer[analyzedUnique[i+2]]);

  circle.on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");})

  .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", **MUST PROTECT THE COLOR IT HAD**);});

}
```

I have searched internet but could not get a result. Thanks in advance.
Image : [The visualization is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SFMH.png)

Comment: Instead of adding a fill explicitely to each circle, I'd rather go for a CSS solution. Simply add/remove a class to each circle on hover/mouseout, you can than comfortably change the style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I'd use the `.classed()` attribute

Example:

```
circle
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).classed("fillCircle", true);})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).classed("fillCircle", false);});
```

and your css would be:

```
.fillCircle{
    fill: red !important;
  }
```

if you use it like this, you will add the class on hover and remove it on mouseout

Comment: maybe add the `!important` tag to override the default?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use the hover pseudo class then you don't need to remember anything.

```js
svg = d3.select("svg");

for (i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) { 

  var circle  = svg.append("circle")

  .attr("cx", 50 + i * 50)

  .attr("cy", 50)

  .attr("r", 20)

  .attr("fill", "blue");
}
```

```css
circle:hover {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
```

Note also that if you make the fill an attribute rather than a style then you don't need !important.

Answer (score 1):

Echonax`s answer is a working one, but this is simpler: give your element a class:

```
circle.attr("class", "myCircle")
```

And use CSS:

```
.myCircle:hover {
    fill: whatever;
;
```